# using <T>(T obj) with a Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, azure

I have the following method

```
public static async void CheckAndInsert<T>(T obj) 
{
    var data = AppDelegate.Self.InstanceLive.LoadAllAsync<T>().Result.ToList();
    if (data.Count != 0)
    {
        var theData = data.FirstOrDefault(t => t.id == obj.id);
        if (theData == null)
            await StoreData(theData);
        else
        {
            if (theData.__updatedAt != obj.__updatedAt)
                await UpdateData(theData);
        }
    }
}
```

The database contains tables generated from an Azure database, so are guaranteed to always have an id.

In theory, this code should work, but on compilation, I'm getting an error that

> Type T does not contain a definition for 'id' and no extension method 'id' of type 'T'

Is there a way to get this code running?

Comment: No, it shouldn't work in theory, I'm afraid. The compiler needs to be sure that any possible type T you use will have an id. To ensure that, you need to set a constraint. C# generics are not the same as C++ templates, despite syntax similarities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble here is that with this generic method declaration `T` can be *any* type, including those that do not provide an `Id` member. Obviously, your code would break in this case, hence it is disallowed by the compiler.

To get around this, you need to provide [generic type constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to constrain T such that you can be sure it has an Id property.

```
public static async void CheckAndInsert<T>(T obj) where T:IIdentity
```

and have your model classes implement `IIdentity` which might look something like

```
public interface IIdentity
{
    int Id{get;}
}
```

Comment: That's got it, just need to figure out why the public string id in the interface is telling me the modifier 'public' is not valid for this item now....

Comment: All interface members are public by default, so you just skip access specifier in interface.